# How to organize circles into coherent "glob"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Johnny's Potential Homepage</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: Abel Regular;
                src: url("fonts/Abel-Regular.ttf");
            }
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            class Circle {
                constructor(x, y, radius) {
                    this.x = x;
                    this.y = y;
                    this.destinationX = x;
                    this.destinationY = y;
                    this.originalRadius = radius;
                    this.radius = radius/2;
                    this.contentAlpha = 0;
                    this.displayDelay = 50;
                    this.displayDelayTicker = 0;
                }
                update() {

                    var offset = Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x-mouseX, 2)+(Math.pow(this.y-mouseY, 2))));
                    var angle = -Math.atan2(this.x-mouseX, this.y-mouseY) - Math.PI/2;
                    this.destinationX = canvas.width / 2 + offset * Math.cos(angle);
                    this.destinationY = canvas.height / 2 + offset * Math.sin(angle);
                    
                    this.fixCollisions();

                    this.x += (this.destinationX - this.x) / 10;
                    this.y += (this.destinationY - this.y) / 10;
                    this.radius += (this.originalRadius - this.radius) / 10;

                    if (this.displayDelayTicker >= this.displayDelay) {
                        this.contentAlpha += (1 - this.contentAlpha) / 10;
                    }
                    this.displayDelayTicker = Math.min(this.displayDelay, this.displayDelayTicker+1);
                }
                draw() {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                    ctx.filter = "blur(120px)";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.filter = "blur(0px)";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                fixCollisions() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                        if (circles[i] != this) {
                            var angle = getAngle([this.x, this.y], [circles[i].x, circles[i].y]);
                            var dist = ((this.radius + circles[i].radius)/2 + padding);

                            // Distribute
                            this.destinationX += Math.cos(-angle) * dist;
                            this.destinationY += Math.sin(-angle) * dist;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            class Centerpiece extends Circle {
                constructor(x, y, radius) {
                    super(x, y, radius);
                    this.time = 0;
                    this.readTime = "";
                    this.readSeconds = "";
                }
                update() {
                    super.update();

                    var date = new Date();
                    var destTime = date.getHours()*3600 + date.getMinutes()*60 + date.getSeconds();
                    
                    if (this.displayDelayTicker >= this.displayDelay) {
                        this.time += (destTime - this.time) / 10;
                    }
                    var hours = Math.floor(this.time / 3600);
                    if (hours > 12) {
                        hours -= 12;
                    }
                    var minutes = (this.time/60) % 60;
                    minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
                    if (minutes < 10) {
                        minutes = "0" + minutes;
                    }
                    var seconds = (this.time) % 60;
                    seconds = Math.floor(seconds);
                    if (seconds < 10) {
                        seconds = "0" + seconds;
                    }
                    this.readTime = hours + ":" + minutes;
                    this.readSeconds = seconds;
                }
                draw() {
                    super.draw();

                    ctx.font = "14px Abel Regular";
                    var secondsWidth = ctx.measureText(this.readSeconds).width;

                    ctx.font = "21px Abel Regular";
                    var timeWidth = ctx.measureText(this.readTime).width;
                    ctx.textAlign = "center";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + this.contentAlpha + ")";
                    ctx.fillText(this.readTime, this.x - secondsWidth/2 -1, this.y);

                    ctx.font = "14px Abel Regular";
                    ctx.fillText(this.readSeconds, this.x + timeWidth/2 + 1, this.y);

                }
            }

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var circles = [];

            var mouseX = canvas.width/2;
            var mouseY = canvas.height/2;

            var scale = 1.0;
            var scrollAmount = 0;
            
            var padding = Math.sqrt(getDistance([0, 0], [canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2]));

            circles.push(new Centerpiece(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 120));
            circles.push(new Centerpiece(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 100));
            circles.push(new Centerpiece(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 80));
            circles.push(new Centerpiece(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 90));

            window.onresize = function() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                var padding = Math.sqrt(getDistance([0, 0], [canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2])) + 10;
            }

            window.onmousemove = function(e) {
                mouseX = e.clientX;
                mouseY = e.clientY;
            }

            window.onwheel = function(e) {
                scrollAmount -= Math.min(Math.max(-0.5, e.deltaY), 0.5);
                scale = (Math.log10(Math.min(2, Math.max(0.5, scrollAmount + 1)))) + 1;
                console.log(scrollAmount + " " + scale);
            }

            function getDistance(a, b) {
                return (Math.sqrt((b[0]-a[0])*(b[0]-a[0])-(b[1]-a[1])*(b[1]-a[1])));
            }

            function getAngle(a, b) {
                return Math.atan2(b[1] - a[1], b[0] - a[0]);
            }

            function loop() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                    circles[i].update();
                }
                
                for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                    circles[i].draw();
                }

                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            }
            loop();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to have the circles "glob" together in the middle, yet not collide. Take a look at the `fixCollisions()` function and see if there's a way to update things so the circles spread evenly across the x and y axis.

Also, I'm not sure why it bugs out at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you need, if I understood correctly. I commented out some lines and changed some others. I removed the mouse following part because I did not get to fix that and it causes a problem by resetting the position of the blobs every time it updates.
Then I changed the way the blobs are made to be attracted to each other but not allowing them to overlap.
I also simplified the way the sines and cosines are calculated. You don't actually need to first find the angle and the take the cosine and sine of the angle since you already have these when dividing the x and y displacements by the distance.  That is in actual fact dividing the opposite and the adjacent sides by the hypotenuse, which is actually the definition of a sine and cosine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Johnny's Potential Homepage</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: Abel Regular;
            src: url("fonts/Abel-Regular.ttf");
        }
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        class Circle {
            constructor(x, y, radius) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.destinationX = x;
                this.destinationY = y;
                this.originalRadius = radius;
                this.radius = radius/2;
                this.contentAlpha = 0;
                this.displayDelay = 50;
                this.displayDelayTicker = 0;
            }
            update() {

                var offset = Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x-mouseX, 2)+(Math.pow(this.y-mouseY, 2))));
                var angle = -Math.atan2(this.x-mouseX, this.y-mouseY) - Math.PI/2;
                //this.destinationX = canvas.width / 2 + offset * Math.cos(angle);
                //this.destinationY = canvas.height / 2 + offset * Math.sin(angle);
                
                this.fixCollisions();

                this.x += (this.destinationX - this.x) / 10;
                this.y += (this.destinationY - this.y) / 10;
                // removed this.radius += (this.originalRadius - this.radius) / 10;
                      
                      // changed
                      this.x += Math.min( 1 * ( canvas.width / 2 - this.x ),1 ); 
                      this.y += Math.min( 1 * ( canvas.height / 2 - this.y ),1 );
                      

                if (this.displayDelayTicker >= this.displayDelay) {
                    this.contentAlpha += (1 - this.contentAlpha) / 10;
                }
                this.displayDelayTicker = Math.min(this.displayDelay, this.displayDelayTicker+1);
            }
            draw() {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                ctx.filter = "blur(120px)";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.filter = "blur(0px)";
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";
                ctx.fill();
            }
            fixCollisions() {
                for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) 
                      {
                    if (circles[i] != this) {
                        //var angle = getAngle([this.x, this.y], [circles[i].x, circles[i].y]);
                        //var dist = ((this.radius + circles[i].radius)/2 + padding);
                        var minDist = ((this.radius + circles[i].radius));
                                 var dist = Math.sqrt( (this.x-circles[i].x)*(this.x-circles[i].x) + (this.y-circles[i].y)*(this.y-circles[i].y) )

                        // Distribute
                        if ( dist < minDist)  // overlapping so push away
                                 {
                                 
                                    this.destinationX += 100 * (( this.x - circles[i].x) / minDist ) / ( dist + 1 );
                                    this.destinationY += 100 * (( this.y - circles[i].y) / minDist ) / ( dist + 1 );
                                 }
                                 
                                 if ( dist > minDist)  // overlapping so push away
                                 {
                                    this.destinationX +=  -0.001 * (( this.x - circles[i].x) / minDist ) * dist;
                                    this.destinationY +=  -0.001 * (( this.y - circles[i].y) / minDist ) * dist;
                                 }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        class Centerpiece extends Circle {
            constructor(x, y, radius) {
                super(x, y, radius);
                this.time = 0;
                this.readTime = "";
                this.readSeconds = "";
            }
            update() {
                super.update();

                var date = new Date();
                var destTime = date.getHours()*3600 + date.getMinutes()*60 + date.getSeconds();
                
                if (this.displayDelayTicker >= this.displayDelay) {
                    this.time += (destTime - this.time) / 10;
                }
                var hours = Math.floor(this.time / 3600);
                if (hours > 12) {
                    hours -= 12;
                }
                var minutes = (this.time/60) % 60;
                minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
                if (minutes < 10) {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                var seconds = (this.time) % 60;
                seconds = Math.floor(seconds);
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }
                this.readTime = hours + ":" + minutes;
                this.readSeconds = seconds;
            }
            draw() {
                super.draw();

                ctx.font = "14px Abel Regular";
                var secondsWidth = ctx.measureText(this.readSeconds).width;

                ctx.font = "21px Abel Regular";
                var timeWidth = ctx.measureText(this.readTime).width;
                ctx.textAlign = "center";
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + this.contentAlpha + ")";
                ctx.fillText(this.readTime, this.x - secondsWidth/2 -1, this.y);

                ctx.font = "14px Abel Regular";
                ctx.fillText(this.readSeconds, this.x + timeWidth/2 + 1, this.y);

            }
        }

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var circles = [];

        var mouseX = canvas.width/2;
        var mouseY = canvas.height/2;

        var scale = 1.0;
        var scrollAmount = 0;
        
        var padding = Math.sqrt(getDistance([0, 0], [canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2]));

        circles.push(new Centerpiece(0.27 * canvas.width, 0.67 *  canvas.height/2, 120));
        circles.push(new Centerpiece(0.98 * canvas.width, 0.23 *  canvas.height/2, 100));
        circles.push(new Centerpiece(0.46 * canvas.width, 0.15 *  canvas.height/2, 80));
        circles.push(new Centerpiece(0.37 * canvas.width, 0.29 *  canvas.height/2, 90));

        window.onresize = function() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            var padding = Math.sqrt(getDistance([0, 0], [canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2])) + 10;
        }

        window.onmousemove = function(e) {
            mouseX = e.clientX;
            mouseY = e.clientY;
        }

        window.onwheel = function(e) {
            scrollAmount -= Math.min(Math.max(-0.5, e.deltaY), 0.5);
            scale = (Math.log10(Math.min(2, Math.max(0.5, scrollAmount + 1)))) + 1;
            console.log(scrollAmount + " " + scale);
        }

        function getDistance(a, b) {
            return (Math.sqrt((b[0]-a[0])*(b[0]-a[0])-(b[1]-a[1])*(b[1]-a[1])));
        }

        function getAngle(a, b) {
            return Math.atan2(b[1] - a[1], b[0] - a[0]);
        }

        function loop() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                circles[i].update();
            }
            
            for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                circles[i].draw();
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }
        loop();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```